# Nativescript Angular live video streaming on CDN

Tags: android, ios, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm looking for something that allows me to stream live video through a CDN for low latency and high transfer speed in my Nativescript Angular application (ios and android).
Can anyone help me?
P.S. I tried with this plugin https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-webrtc-plugin
but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you elaborate what didn't work? Did you report it to plugin author by raising an issue in the Github repo?